# I want to generate a bool value when I click a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to execute some scripts only when the user confirms.
Sample code like this

```
if 'confirm' is clicked, then $confirm = true;   

if($confirm)
 {
   some script
 }
else
 {
   other script
 }
 ?>
```

there are two buttons 'confirm' and 'discard'.  If confirm is clicked then $confirm = true;

Comment: You have to use javascript or jquery for that

Comment: check `confirm()` in javascript or jQuery dialogs or something like that

Comment: You can't have the php code on the client machine, it'll only be on your server. So you need to either make an AJAX call to send the option (true/false) user clicked to your server and then send back the response to the client or else use javascript on the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two buttons like this

```
<input type="button" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="confirm">
<input type="button" name="discard" id="discard" value="discard">
```

You can use jquery event handlers for getting which button is clicked like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#confirm").on('click',function(){
     alert('Confirm clicked');
     //If you need to communicate with the server the do an ajax call here
   });

   $("#discard").on('click',function(){
     alert('Discard clicked');
     //If you need to communicate with the server the do an ajax call here
   });
});
```

You can check for the click event reference from [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do with php, extract state of fields with environment php variables, you just make an formular and send some data to your webserver script-file.

```
<?php
$confirm = $_POST["name_of_the_button"]
if(isset($confirm))
 {
   some script
 }
else
 {
   other script
 }
```

**-----EDIT-----:**

I made it with two files:

**File: form.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Button test</title>
<script type="application/javascript">
function ajaxObj()
{
   var xmlHttp=null;
   try
   {
      // Browsers Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari;
      xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      try
      {
         // Browser Internet Explorer;
         xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
         try
         {
            // Other browsers
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         catch(e)
         {
            // Your browser does not suport XMLhttp object
            alert('Your browser does not suport XMLhttp object');
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   return xmlHttp;
}

function doQuery(id)
{
    xmlHttp=ajaxObj();
    if(xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert('Your browser does not suport XMLhttp object');
        return;
    }
    xmlHttp.open("POST","check.php",true);
    var send = 'id='+id;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(send);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="confirmed" name="button" onclick="doQuery(this.id)">Confirm</button>
<button id="declined" name="button" onclick="doQuery(this.id)">Decline</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**File check.php:**

```
<?php
$action = $_POST["id"];
$confirm = false;
if($action=="confirmed")
    $confirm = true;
else if($action=="declined")
    $confirm = false;
else {}
?>
```

Comment: <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="confirm">
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) --------- this will work, again type is not button, it's submit
            {
                echo "Hiiiiiiiiiiii";
            }
         ?>
        </form>

Comment: Then you need to use AJAX, on button click to make a ajax call. Then in php you will check id of button that called that script.

Comment: I will post a solution, if didn't fiind it. UPDATED my post.

Answer (score 0):

if You use javascript then use belo:-

```
if(window.confirm("please confirm"))
{
    return true;
    // or do Your operation.
}
else{
    return false;
    // or do Your operation.
}
```

otherwise You can use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="confirm"> 
<input type="button" name="discard" id="discard" value="discard">

$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("input:button").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).id == 'confirm'){ 
      // put your script here
    }else{ 
      // put your script here }   
    });

});
```